# Turning off the Dialog in Acrobat when opening from sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007, registry, integration, acrobat

I am opening Acrobat X Pro to edit PDF documents from Sharepoint 2007, but when you choose edit either from the popup dialog, or the Sharepoint context menu, Acrobat always prompts for Checkout&Open or Open.  Is there a way to disable this dialog so that it always chooses Checkout&Open?

I have discovered that if the document is already checked out to me, the dialog doesn't appear.  Is there perhaps a way to silently checkout a document on the sharepoint side or acrobat side when a user chooses "Edit Document"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get around this dialog by creating my own OpenDocuments control in c#.  The control is called instead of AdobeAcrobat.OpenDocuments and after checking out the file in sharepoint through a webservice call, it repeats the call but directs to the acrobat OpenDocuments control.  This allows acrobat to open and think it was called directly from sharepoint, but since the file was checked out already by the user, the dialog doesn't need to appear.